# Ruta desde donde bajar actualizacion de aplicacion windows form visual studio 2015

Tags: .net

Uso visual studio .net 2015. Programo en visual basic. Utilizo el framework 4.6

Tengo una aplicación que 'la publico' en mi sitio web bajo windos IIS. El destino es del tipo

ftp://usuario:contraseña@misitio/miprograma/

Eso lo hace ok... porque cuando voy al sitio ([www.misitio.com/miprograma](http://www.misitio.com/miprograma)) (si no existe) me  crea la carpeta miprograma y copia los archivos de la instalacion...

incluso como prueba bajo estos archivos en un pc... ejecuto el setup.exe se instala y funciona correctamente

El problema lo tengo con las actualizaciones automáticas.

Establezco que mi aplicacion buscara actualizaciones y como ruta pongo http://www.misitio.com/miprograma

La cuestion que cuando recompilo y subo una nueva revisión (en la ruta destino [www.misitio.com/miprograma](http://www.misitio.com/miprograma) en la carpeta Application Files se agrega una subcarpeta con la nueva revision...)

Sin embargo cuan en la pc ejecuto la version anterior de mi programa... veo que como que intenta buscar si hay una nueva version.. pero simplemente ejecuta la misma instalada y no me propone bajar/instalar la nueva... que estoy haciendo mal?

Gracias.

Hugo